# Header style change when page scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

i have purchased  [this](http://themeforest.net/item/clinico-premium-medical-and-health-theme/full_screen_preview/8676548) 
wordpress theme  and customizing it myself  ,  at the momnent when  the page scrolls down its  header styles  change ,  it remains stuck  on top as   fixed position and logo+ navigation get smaller in size . Problem is that our logo has some small text that is not visible when it turns  to smaller one ,  i am really unable to get the option in theme to  sort out this  issue that when it scrolls down styles should not change , can someone help me with it Please  i did google and found that scrolltop()> some width  function   may work but that is not working for me

Comment: can you post some code so we can help you? Thanks!

Comment: as requested   i mentioned link to theme i really dont  know which code  is working for this part there are more  than 10 ...min.js files in  the js folder

Comment: Then you might want to spend some time better-defining the question so it can be answered :)